# How to share devices in ubuntu with samba?

Tags: samba, shared-folders

How can I share a device like my external HDD attached to my ubuntu machine?
I share some folders on my ubuntu, but I cannot share the device.
I want to connect to it with MacOS and I always get the error connection and then ask me to call administrator.

I use this code in samba :

```
[ADATA710]
path = /media/xxx/ADATA710
available = yes
valid users = xxx
read only = no
browsable = yes
public = yes
writable = yes
```

Comment: Did you add xxx to the samba password database? sudo smbpasswd -a xxx

Comment: Yes i added it before.  I have no problem with other folders shared on ubuntu

Comment: The only 2 possibilities I can think of is [1] The xxx in /media/xxx doesn't have access to ADATA710 on the Linux box itself, [2] The xxx in /media/xxx and the xxx in valid users are two different users.

Comment: It was for ubuntu. after i restart the system now it works .